# input text changes focus on safari

Tags: css, input, onfocus

I hope someone can help me out with this. I have a search box on my site and when I try to type something in it (safari mobile). The layout changes. As you can see below:
[image: preview]

is there any css rule that would make the input field fixed no matter if is is focused or not. SO the layout remains the same.

I tried this rule

```
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
```